# Why does Newtonsoft.Json serializes byte[] as base64 but sbyte[] not?

Tags: c#, serialization, json.net, base64

byte[] encoding in base64,sbyte[] does not.

```
byte[] bs = {100,101};
Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(bs);//"ZGU="

sbyte[] sbs = {100,101};
Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(sbs);//"[100,101]"
```

Comment: it's really strange to me, i've reproduced locally. searched the docs but didn't find quick answer.

Comment: `byte[]` is standard way to represent binary data in objects - some of them could be non-printable ASCII characters. So using ascii character is not an option. Base64 encode string is shorter than comma seperated list of numbers; hence the convention of using Base64. If you really want to use `byte` as tyni integer values, try declaring it as `Collection<byte>` or `List<byte>`.

Comment: I just want to know why does not sbyte[] serialize as Base64

Answer (score 8):

It's just the way JSON.Net works, and I would suspect most serialisers do the same.  Check the [documentation](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/SerializationGuide.htm#PrimitiveTypes) which explicitly says that `byte[]` is serialised as a base64 encoded string.

All other arrays are treated as you would expect, as simple JSON array types where the elements are serialised according to the rules for the array's type. Meaning that `sbyte[]` will be serialised as an array of integers.

Comment: How does Google-gson deserialize json string encoded in base64?

Answer (score 2):

The [serialization guide](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/SerializationGuide.htm) in the documentation for JSON.Net shows that there is no serialization rule for `sbyte[]` array.  There is, however, an entry for `sbyte`. `sbyte` will be serialized as `int`.

`byte[]` arrays will be serialized to a `base64` string since it is explicitly defined in the guide, and as a convenience.

Since there is no rule for `sbyte[]` in the serialization guide the array will be treated like any other array, and it's members will be serialized according to the guide.  Therefore, `sbyte[]` is serialised to `int[]` since `sbyte` serilaizes to `int`.

Please see image below:

[image]